# How to implement java library that is simply a .java file

Tags: java, import, libraries

I'm attempting to use the PasswordStorage class found at the following github repo:

https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/

I've found the PasswordStorage.java file but don't know where to go from there. I am under the impression that I need a .jar file to import it as a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy that file **and** the `LICENSE` file into your own source code

You don't need a JAR for it.

Comment: Do I place them both in the same file, with the LICENSE above the code, and then reference it normally?

Comment: That is one way to do it, I guess. Typically, you would have one LICENSE file yourself with different sections mentioning the libraries included in your code, but that is more a legal question